# Using variable_set with associative array

Tags: 7, forms

I use checkboxes in a form to capture a users selection as:

```
$form['mbo_block_config']['livembo_classes_details'] = array(
                '#type' => 'checkboxes',
                '#title' => t('Class Details'),
                '#description' => t('Choose class details to display.'),
                '#options' => $details,
                '#default_value' => variable_get('livembo_classes_details', array('c_id','c_cd_name')),
                '#required' => TRUE,                
                );
```

The available options are stored in $details which is an associative array:

```
$details = array(
          'c_id' => t('Class ID'),
          'c_cd_name' => t('Class Name'),
          'c_cd_description' => t('Class Description'),
          'c_l_name' => t('Location: Name'),
          'c_l_city' => t('Location: City'),
          'c_l_full' => t('Location: Full Address'),
          'c_l_phone' => t('Location: Contact Number'),
          'c_s_FullName' => t('Staff: Name'),     
          'c_start ' => t('Class Start Time'),
          'c_end' => t('Class End Time')
          );
```

I use variable set `variable_set('livembo_classes_details', $edit['livembo_classes_details']);` which works fine, however it flattens the array and changes the keys to values as per:

```
Array ( [0] => c_id [1] => c_l_phone [2] => c_l_name )
```

How can I retain the key/value format in the array as originally specified? For example:

```
Array ( [c_id] => t('Class ID') [c_l_phone] => t('Location: Contact Number') [c_l_name] => t('Location: Name') )
```

Comment: there is something wrong with $edit['livembo_classes_details']. variable_get and variable_set work fine with keyed arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not variable_get()/set(). It stores whatever you pass to it as a serialized array.

However, what you are saving are the *keys* of your array, because that's what is passed from the browser when submitting the form. This is also what is expected in the #default_value so it needs to be like this.

When accessing the information, all you need to do is get the intersection of your $details and the selected keys like this:

```
$selected_details = array_intersect_key($details, array_flip(variable_get('livembo_classes_details', array('c_id','c_cd_name')));
```

I would recommend to add a helper function which returns $details if you haven't already, so you can re-use that definition and a second helper function which contains the above code.

Comment: Sorted! So simple, cant believe I was so hung up on it when its more of a html form issue.. Thanks

Comment: As a general advice, I strongly recommend to use the dpm() (readable display of arrays/objects) and ddebug_backtrace() (readable backtrace) functions whenever something doesn't work as expected. Add dpm($variable) for anything relevant to see it's content so that you know that you're working with. In case of forms, print $form_state['values']/$edit.